# Seekbar where I can change both min max value with 2 thumbs

Tags: android, android-seekbar, material-components-android, rangeseekbar, android-slider

I want to have a thumb for both min and max for my seekbar. You should be able to drag both thumbs independently.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use the `RangeSlider` in Material Components and the method [`setValues()`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.2.0-alpha05/lib/java/com/google/android/material/slider/Slider.java#L631)

```
    <com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
        android:id="@+id/slider"            
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="10"
        ../>
```

with:

```
RangeSlider slider = findViewById(R.id.slider);
slider.setValues(1.0f,5.0f);
```

[image]

You can also use:

```
    <com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
        android:id="@+id/slider"            
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="10"
        app:values="@array/initial_slider_values"
        ../>
```

with `res/values/arrays.xml`:

```
<resources>
  <array name="initial_slider_values">
    <item>1.0</item>
    <item>5.0</item>
  </array>
</resources>
```

**Note:** This requires a minimum of version **1.2.0-beta01**

Comment: `1.2.0-beta01` of what?

Comment: @rekire Material Components library 1.2.0

Comment: It is possible without set android:valueTo="10" in xml ?

Comment: @TusharLathiya There is default value of 1.0f if you don't specify it

Comment: @TusharLathiya Just use slider.valueTo = 30f. You can use values greater than 1.0f programmatically

Comment: @TusharLathiya It is just an example. Use the value you need.

Answer (score 3):

The normal seekbar in android can't have two thumbs that can be changed.

Instead use Slider from the Material Compoments Library.
https://material.io/components/sliders/#

Dependencies we need to include is:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'
```

Example layout to test this slider

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
      android:id="@+id/slider"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:value="12.34"
      android:valueFrom="0.0"
      android:valueTo="50.0" />

  <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
    android:id="@+id/rangeSlider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:valueFrom="0.0"
    android:valueTo="100.0" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In your activity set up the range slider with two thumbs:

```
Slider rangeSlider = findViewById(R.id.rangeSlider);
rangeSlider.setValues(0.0F, rangeSlider.getMaximumValue());
```

In your styles.xml change from AppCompat to MaterialComponents, like this:

```
From: parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
To:   parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Now we have a slider with two thumbs!
[image: Range slider]